# Как вывести запись из БД в формате json

Tags: json, laravel

В БД имеется запись в формате JSON
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь Вывести в цикле

```
            @foreach($products as $item)
                <p>{{ $item->product_id }}</p>
                <p>{{ $item->value->price }}</p>
            @endforeach
```

выдает ошибку - "Trying to get property of non-object"

В чем может быть дело?

Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Вам поможет метод `json_decode()`
Ссылка на [документацию](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php)